# My Amazon Cognito have an invalid token signature

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-amplify

I am working on Amazon cognito, I'm trying to delegate my authentification to my company provider, everything looks good in the process, until the very last step when cognito is supposed to deliver the token.
I'm having this error : `error_description=invalid_token_signature%3A+The+secret+length+must+be+at+least+256+bits&state=ezffEQ9s16SXiWfJIoGSjwVsjXm9s8JT&error=invalid_request`

my user pool dont have any client_secret, but i already tried with a secret and the same issue is triggered.

To trigger the amazon cognito i'm using the Amplify Cognito lib.
If anyone have any idea that could help me please